# Pull request in Bitbucket: unrelated branches

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I want for my team to be able to review code on Bitbucket. We have a repo with many commits. I created a new branch with only the code I wanted to review. Basically, I took the branch with the whole codebase that was never reviewed and removed all the parts I did not want to review with `git rm --cached -r`. I tried two things.

First I created a new orphan branch, removed everything from it, again with `git rm --cached -r`. I tried to create a pull request towards this new branch, but Bitbucket said:

> The following error(s) occurred saving this pull request:
>   Unrelated branches

So I went back to a very early commit with nothing in it. I branched from there. It is a direct ancestor of the branch that contains the code I want to review. I tried to start a pull request again. Again, I got:

> The following error(s) occurred saving this pull request:
>   Unrelated branches

No matter what I do, I get that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I made a wrong assumption in the description above. The source branch was actually another orphaned branch into which I had copied the code. So the two branches were in fact unrelated and git had no way of know in what way they were related. My bad.